C++ Builder 64 bit connecting to MS Access 64 bit
The problem is I’m trying to connect a C++ Builder CE 11.3 program (64 bit) to a MS Access database (64 bit).
I’m using:
Embarcadero C++ Builder CE 11.3 with the target platform being Windows 64 bit
MS Access 2019 64 bit edition for the database.  I have the 64 bit version of Office Professional Plus 2019 Click to Run.
I’ve manually entered the following connection string:
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source="C:\CAT\Test\Database2.accdb";Persist Security Info=False;

I get the following error:
"provider cannot found it may not be installed properly"
When I try to build it using the connection wizard the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 is not listed:

It appears that the ODBC Data Source administrator has the drivers:

Been chasing this around for some time.  Most solutions seem to involve making sure that the target platform is the same as the database.  Which I think I got covered.  Also reloading the MS Access database engine.
Some of the things I’ve tried:

Uninstall/Reinstall accessdatabasengine_X64.
Uninstall MS Office then Reinstall accessdatabasengine_X64.
Install MSAccess AccessRuntime_x64_en-us.
I tried different versions of Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 (12.0, 15.0)

At this point I’ve tried pretty much everything I could think off and could find on the internet with no solution.
Help
At this point I'm pretty sure I'm using MS Access 64 bit version:
enter image description here
As fare as C++ Builder I'm not as sure although it seem to indicate I'm using the 64 bit target
enter image description here
It appears that C++ Builder is not working in a 64 bit environment???  When bringing up the connection string provider the 64 bit providers don't seem to be there.

Are you sure you're working with a 64-bit program? Because those listed providers are clearly 32-bit

I have done this in the past (reading MSAccess 97 *.mdb tables using FireDAC in a C++ Builder VCL Windows 64 bit app) so it is possible. You need to make sure you do not have a 32bit version of MS Access installed on the machine.

My code includes this useful (hopefully) function:

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// the ODBCAdvanced settings are obtained by using a TFDConnection and then
// using the connection wizard to generate the settings
String TMyClassNameHere::GetMSAccessODBCAdvanced(String Directory)
{
return String{"DefaultDir="} +
Directory +
String{";DriverId=281;MaxBufferSize=32767;MaxScanRows=8;PageTimeout=500;SafeTransactions=0;Threads=10;UserCommitSync=Yes"};
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
